# What's the meaning of "made my brain claw at my skull"?

Tags: meaning

I searched many dictionaries but didn't get the meaning.

Could you please explain it to me?

The full text is here:

The burn was the injury, I reasoned. It made sense to treat it first. I
fetched a pack of ice from the chest freezer on the patio, but when the pack
touched his leg he screamed—a back-arching, eye-popping scream that
**made my brain claw at my skull**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is figurative language, and you can compare it with figurative language in your native tongue.

To "claw" is to scratch with claws.  A dog may claw at a door when it wants to be let out.

Of course, your brain doesn't have actual claws, but the feeling that the author gets from the scream makes her feel like her brain is an animal that is scratching the inside of her head.
This is a metaphor. You will find that your own language also uses metaphors.

Answer (score 1):

The writer is trying to describe the empathetic pain he felt from the person who was burnt, whose severe reaction to the application of ice showed that another injury was probably much worse than the burn. It is a description of what his own brain feels to be doing to the inside of his skull – a metaphor, as if his brain has claws which can physically scrape the inside of his skull.

Answer (score -1):

It's very figurative language, as others have indicated. I don't think it's an established idiom with a set meaning, but here is how I would paraphrase the entire passage using more literal language:

> **Original**:
>   ...he screamed — a *back-arching, eye-popping scream* that *made my brain claw at my skull*.
>
> **Paraphrase**:
>   ...he screamed — a *very loud scream* that *made my head hurt*.

although it's possible the author was trying to convey more of an emotional response than a physical one, that is, something like:

> **Alternate Paraphrase**:
>   ...he screamed — a *loud scream* that *caught my attention and filled me with a sense of panic*.